# Return breakes loop

Tags: java, loops, return

I have this code:

```
static String clock;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    time();
    clock = time();
    result();
}

public static String time()
{
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();

    int Hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int Min = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int Sec = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);

    String time = Hour + ":" + Min + ":" + Sec;

    return "[" + time + "]";
}
```

I want use this time more times but the time is still the same. Example:

```
public static void result()
{
    try
    {
        Print("Loading textures");
        Thread.sleep(2500);
        Print("Loading sounds");
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        Print("Loading events");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        Print("Loaded");

    } catch (Exception e)
    {}
}
```

I need this code in loop but I dont know how... Can somebody help me please?

Comment: I think someone writing out the code for you will do you more harm than good. You should take a look at [this link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm) and learn a little about loops. Post that effort, if you are still struggling, please let me know.

Comment: I don't see `time()` being used in your example.

Comment: I think you are storing the result from time() method and using it multiple times, instead call the time() method everytime you want to use it. Add the code where you are using the time() method

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Where is the call for time() in your example?
If you want to generate new time, means current time, you need to call time() function.
for example:

```
String currentTime=time();
...
//some code
...
currentTime=time();//initializing current time
```